# Android ImageView and Bitmap on canvas don't have the same size

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a Bitmap image in my ressources.

When i draw it using an ImageView, it doesn't have the same size as when I draw it on the canvas using Drawbitmap.
No matter what density I use to my bitmap ( 160, 240 ), the bitmap is always zoomed.
How to draw the bitmap so it has the same size as when I use an imageview ?

Comment: Post your current `Canvas` drawing code.

Comment: c.drawBitmap(mImg.mBmp, mImg.mMatrix, mImg.mPaint);

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a scaled bitmap and then draw.

```
my_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.my_bitmap);
my_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(my_bitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
```